# Cordova and php - compare two values in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I have a webapplication where I push data to a table (User_Info) which includes a random generated token and Sur- and Lastname. Now when I type in the cordova application the token it gets sends to a table named (User_Token). Now I want to check if that token in User_Token matches the generated token in User_Info. If they match I want to show that specific data.

This is my cordova html:

```
<input type="text" class="valueToken" name="usertoken" >
<button type="submit" class="postToken" id="submit" />PostToken </button>
```

This is my cordova js:

```
 $('.postToken').click(function(){
   console.log($('.valueToken').val());
   var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  "http://example.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_token.php",
       data: { dataString: tokenValue },
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
          alert("Order Submitted");
          }
   });
});
```

and this is the php on server side:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$stringData = $_POST['dataString']; 

echo $stringData;    
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$insertToken = "INSERT INTO User_Token(Oefening_Token) VALUES ('$stringData')";
$tokenresult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertToken);

if($tokenresult){
    echo "Successful";
}else {
    echo "Error description: " .  (mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

So how can I achieve to check if it matches after that button press and if it matches show data.

This is btw the ajax get call:

```
$.ajax({
        url:     "http://example.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_schema.php",
        type:    "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            /* ...use the data to fill in some HTML elements... */
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
        },
        error:   function() {
            /* ...show an error... */
        }
    });
```

and this the php to get data from that table:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$sqlGetSchema = "SELECT * FROM `Oefeningen`";
$result = $conn->query($sqlGetSchema);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $token = $row["Token"];
        $surname = $row['Surname'];    
        $lastname = $row['Lastname'];

        echo "<div class='". $token . "'><p>Token: " . $token . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Surname: " . $surname ." Lastname:" . $lastname. "</p>"; 
    }
} else {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So basically what I want to achieve is to compare the input value from cordova app in table User_Token with token in the other table. When it matches it has to show all content of matched token row.